# Reasons for git support in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, svn

Is there any specific reason why Apple integrated ONLY git support in Xcode and not SVN? I know there are workarounds to make svn work in Xcode but they seem like pain compared to intuitive setup of git.

Comment: I don't think there is an answer to this question, unless an Apple employee involved in the decision shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Because more users asked for Git than for Subversion?
- Because Subversion support doesn't really make sense without support for managing and setting up Subversion repositories, which would be more complex (and thus expensive to implement) than Git support?
- Because Git is cool and hip, and Apple wants to be, too?
- Because someone, somewhere, flipped a coin?
- Because it was added at roughly the same time as Ruby support, and Git is *the* dominant VCS in the Ruby community?

You'd really have to ask someone at Apple.

Comment: Sounds like that, I didn't want to believe at first, that Apple would just...ban SVN for its "age", but seems like that is the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SVN is a really outdated system. Git is here the better choice and work very well so i think there is no sin to implement an older system.

There are some solution to import SVN to GIT.

Comment: Subversion is not _that_ outdated, and Git is not always a better choice, such as when you work in a company with a decade long investment in Subversion with no easy migration path to Git, owing to _infrastructure dependence_ (not just developer dependence) on SVN.

Comment: Why you shouldn't have a migration path to GIT? I think we can discuss this now but i know SVN, and i have worked a long time when it. GIT is a really a better solution then SVN. Reclusive when you look at the Story of GIT. That Linus Torvalds build them because he want a better version control then SVN and a peripheral structure.

Comment: I didn't say _no_ migration path, I said no _easy_ migration path. When dozens or hundreds of projects are built stored in svn, and things like application deployments are dependent on svn, the migration is a large time investment.

Comment: In this case SVN<->Git gateway would be an easy solution. As I heard (though I'm not sure), in Facebook devs use Git interface but other infrastructure uses Subversion.